# Why last column of table starts printing outside table

Tags: php

I want to print a table of this week with the tasks you have to do each day, but for a certain reason the first value of the task column is printed above the table and the second value is shown in the first task cell. For this reason, the last cell of the last column is always empty. How do I fix this?

```
$weekdagen = ["maandag","dinsdag","woensdag","donderdag","vrijdag","zaterdag","zondag"];
//today
$vandaag = date("d-m-Y",time());
//day of week starting on Monday (-1)
$weekdag = date('w', strtotime($vandaag)) -1;

$i = 0;
//get first day of this week
$startWeek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.($weekdag).' days'));
$datum = $startWeek;

while($i<7)
{
    print '<tr>
    <td>'.$weekdagen[$i+1].'</td>
    <td>'.$datum.'</td>
    <td>' .printTasks($datum); '</td>
    </tr>';
    $i++;
    $datum = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datum.' +1 days'));
}

function printTasks($date) {
    $sql = "SELECT taa_omschr FROM taken where taa_datum = '".$date."'";
    $res = SQLexec($sql);

    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { print $row[taa_omschr] . '<br>'; }
}
```

I changed my SQL statement to $date - 1 day so the right task is shown next to the right date, but it doesn't solve the problem that the last cell is empty.

Comment: You have error in code. Replace `;` with `.` after `printTasks()` to also print ending tag `</td>`

Comment: you have another error: while($I<7) will be infinite, change with $i

Comment: Also, don't mix English with whatever other languages in your source code...

Comment: @Justinas, I found I have to use return in my function instead of print because otherwise it will print all tasks above the table. When I used ; instead of . it only printed the first value above the table.